# Easily add script tags to nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Basically I need to add the script to the head of my index.html,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://a.optmnstr.com/app/js/api.min.js" data-account="XXXXX" data-user="XXXXX" async></script>
```

so what I've tried is...

in my nuxt.config.js

```
head: {
    script: [
        {  
           type: 'text/javascript', 
           src: 'https://a.optmnstr.com/app/js/api.min.js',
           data-account: 'XXXXX',
           data-user: 'XXXXX',
           async: true
        }
    ]
}
```

now obviously this isn't working since `data-account` and `data-user` is not valid, so how can I make this work??

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You could try and look at [this](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#app-template) or [this](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta#__dangerouslydisablesanitizers-string).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was pointed out be @Andrew1325

In nuxt.js you can create a `app.html` file and add scripts to it, so in my case the `app.html` file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://a.optmnstr.com/app/js/api.min.js" data-account="XXXX" data-user="XXXX" async></script>
</html>
```

IMO this is a very easy way to include difficult scripts into your project

**NOTE**

You will need to restart your project to see the `app.html` changes

For more information you can go [nuxtjs - app template](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#app-template)

Comment: How do you add js that is in the assets folder rather than externally

Comment: This solution was validated by @atinux here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1580#issuecomment-327114193

Comment: This solution works. One question, how to add the custom HEAD script only for production `(target: 'static')` ? And avoid loading it while working on `development`?

Answer (score 9):

You can also just enclose the data attributes in single quotes like this:

```
head: {
    script: [
        {  
            type: 'text/javascript', 
            src: 'https://a.optmnstr.com/app/js/api.min.js',
            'data-account': 'XXXXX',
            'data-user': 'XXXXX',
            async: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**This could help you**

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      message: '',
      head: {
        type: Object,
        default: function () {
          return {
            title: ' Default Home page  ',
            meta: [
              {
                'hid': 'description',
                'name': ' description',
                'content': ' Home page  content '
              }
            ],
            script: [
              {
                innerHTML: {
                  'url': 'https://www.example.com',
                  'logo': 'https://www.example.com/icon/logo.png',
                  'parentOrganization': {
                    'name': 'The X Company Inc',
                    'url': 'https://example.io',
                    'logo': 'https://example.io/logo-est.png',
                    '@type': 'Organization'
                  },
                  'foundingLocation': {
                    'address': {
                      'addressLocality': 'Dakar',
                      'addressRegion': 'Selegal',
                      '@type': 'PostalAddress'
                    },
                    '@type': 'Place'
                  },
                  'sameAs': ['https://www.facebook.com/example', 'https://www.twitter.com/example'],
                  '@context': 'http://schema.org',
                  '@type': 'Organization'
                },
                type: 'application/ld+json'
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```